# How to convert from SCPI to legible values?

Tags: python, parsing, instrumentation

I am measuring the current of a circuit with a SourceMeter. However, I am getting the values in SCPI format and am not sure how to convert that to legible output. Here are some examples of the output I'm receiving:  b'7.572'  and  b'05,+9'

I have already tried using   .decode('utf-8')   but this just returns the same thing, without the b in front.

How would I convert these to my actual current values?

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by: `actual current values`? Did you try: `float(b'7.572')`?

Comment: By actual current values, I mean converting the returned text to my current value. For example, a current I measured was 3.1767mA as shown on the SourceMeter, and Python returned '316E-05,+9'. I do not know how to translate the returned value to the actual current.

Comment: So surely the documentation on the serial protocol details the format?

Comment: Probably, but I cannot find that!

Comment: I found a [manual](https://download.tek.com/manual/2400S-900-01_K-Sep2011_User.pdf)

Comment: I have seen that, but I cannot find anything about the output and how to decode it :/

Comment: I see there is this [library](https://pymeasure.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/instruments/keithley/keithley2400.html)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem recently with python and my solution was to do the following:

```
#-- Get reading
sourcemeter.write(":READ?")
reading = sourcemeter.read_bytes(1)

#-- Convert to float
reading = str(reading)
reading = reading.split("'")
reading = reading[1].split("\\")
reading = float(reading[0])
```